# "Npm install --global" and "--save" together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I was wondering if makes any sense to use in the *npm install* command the --global and the --save parameters all together. For example:

```
npm install gulp -g -s
```

As far as I know there is no package.json in the npm system folder, so I suppose the answer is "no", but I want to clear all doubt.

Comment: as i know npm install gulp should be enough for installing gulp to nodejs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `npm install` command does not support installing a module both globally and save it to the package.json in one step.

There is, however, a way to install a module globally indirectly. The package.json supports a preinstall property like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install -g gulp"
}
```

As soon as you execute `npm install`, gulp will be installed globally. Please note that your current user then needs permission to write to your global node module directory.