# Issues install nodemon and finding files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemon, rest

[link to my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BTcl.png)

So I am trying to follow along with a Rest API and node.js tutorial and every time I got to install nodemon I get some weird error that says NPM  can not find a file that is specified? Is this a path issue or something else?

I have already tried clearing my cache and starting again from scratch but I can't quite seem to put my finger on exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Please paste your error message directly into your question, never link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

So, having a look at the error stack, it seems like you're trying to install nodemon as a dependency by including the --save argument, but you're also using the -g argument which means you're trying to install nodemon globaly. Either do:

`npm install -g nodemon` to install nodemon to your machine

or:

`npm install --save-dev nodemon` to include nodemon as a development-only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

NPM Does not support using both `--save` and `-g`. This is because `--save` (or `-s`) attempts to save the module in your `package.json`, while `-g` attempts to save your module globally. However, for globally installed modules, there is no `package.json` file, as they are installed to your entire computer, not just one project. (More information on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056275/npm-install-global-and-save-together))

Install nodemon either through `npm install nodemon` or `npm install nodemon -g` (or `npm install nodemon --save-dev` to save it as only a development dependency)

Comment: Ok I have tried every suggestion in your answer and none of them produce a different error.  I still am having the same issue while using all of these different install methods.